# custom menu option button android

Tags: android

I'm searching for the custom menu option button in which i want to set my custom button add selector over menu button's means to change the image after click.
please look at the sample image, this is normal option menu comes when menu click [image: enter image description here]![enter image description here]

and this when user click on menu button [image: enter image description ![enter image description here]here]

i'm not getting proper solution on this.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: First 2 lines of your query aren't very clear. Could you re-phrase it again?

Comment: okay.i want to make my option menu button look's likes as in first image and also have to give the selector to the button when after click like in second image. can i inflate the linear layout for the menu option.?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at below article.

[Custom Menu](http://staticallytyped.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/android-how-can-you-implement-a-custom-menu-class/)

I think you'll find a way to meet your requirement here for sure :)

Comment: Hi Gagan.Thanks it work to give the selector for the menu button but it's not looking proper because android also have it's default selector which is of yellow color in emulator.Do you getting what i'm talking about.

Comment: General phenomena is: When you set background of a `View` then the default attributes of that `View` are taken away and the `View` will be drawn based on new attributes provided by the developer. In your case, if you set a `selector` as background for any of your `Menu-Buttons` then the same should behave accordingly. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes you are right i'm giving the selector to menu option button but i'm not customising it. i only set the android:icon="@drawable/option_menu_selector" in menu.xml. But how to remove the Android default selector which change the color to of menu option when click.

Comment: If any one know the solution please help me.!